# наследуется приватный метод

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Еще вопрос , уважаемые согласно http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php  если установлен модификатор доступа private то данный метод\свойство не наследуется дочерними классами.

> Модификатор private (закрытый) ограничивает область видимости так, что только класс, где объявлен сам элемент, имеет к нему доступ.

Теперь вот такой вот прикол я создал базовый класс и его экземпляр, потом унаследовался от базового ( RotaryWindow) и к своему удивлению я вижу что ПРИВАТНЫЙ метод базового класса calcValueWindow() успешно работает и в дочерном классе. Как такое происходит ? Вот листинг.

```
 class Window {
private $baseValueWindow;
private $area;
private $perimetr;

const transferToMetersQw =  1000000;
const transferToMeters = 1000;

public function __construct($width, $height, $valueglazing, $valueprofile) {
    $this->area = $this->calcArea($width, $height);
    $this->perimetr = $this->calcPerimetr($width, $height);
    $this->baseValueWindow = $this->calcValueWindow($valueglazing, $valueprofile);
}

public function getBaseValue() {
    return $this->baseValueWindow;
}

private function calcArea($width, $height) {
    return($width * $height)/self::transferToMetersQw;
}

private function calcPerimetr($width, $height) {
    return (2*($width + $height))/self::transferToMeters; 
}    

private function calcValueWindow($valueglazing,$valueprofile) {
    return $valueglazing * $this->area + $valueprofile * $this->perimetr;
}    
}

 class RotaryWindow extends Window {
   // private $valueFindings; будем получать из БД 
private $valueFindings;

 }

    $w = 1000; 
    $h = 1000; 
    $g = 200;
    $s = 25;

    $window1 = new Window($w, $h, $g, $s);
    $value1 = $window1->getBaseValue();   


    $w = 2000; 
    $h = 2000; 
    $g = 500;
    $s = 50;

    $window2 = new RotaryWindow($w, $h, $g, $s);
    $value2 = $window2->getBaseValue();
```

Comment: Вы сами переиначиваете то, что написано.... цитируете доки `Модификатор private (закрытый) ограничивает область видимости так, что только класс, где объявлен сам элемент, имеет к нему доступ.` в которых абсолютно нигде не сказано что `если установлен модификатор доступа private то данный метод\свойство не наследуется дочерними классами.` ........перечитайте предложение из доков несколько раз.

Comment: спасибо , действительно неправильно трактовал )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приватный метод `calcValueWindow()` вызывается в конструкторе `Window`, который вызывается при создании экземпляра `RotaryWindow`, поэтому никакого конфликта доступа нету.